# Twitter send a tweet from a pop-up window

Tags: java, twitter

I have a game in which I am trying to integrate `Twitter` tweet post functionality. What I want is to have a button which, when you click on it, opens a new browser window and has a tweet already loaded for you which you can then press `Tweet`, and the tweet will be posted on your timeline.

It seems I am looking for a Twitter API integration tool but I have no idea what this functionality is called. As a side note, I am using Java and developing the game with `LibGDX`, so I was also wondering if anyone knows of a good Twitter API for Android?

Comment: Hey dude, have you found an answer to your question? I want to make exactly the same thing as you, a game using LibGDX and share score with facebook and twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to actually search for your answer before posting a question in here. This is actually a fairly common question with already an established API that can be found through a simple search.

[Best twitter api for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131124/best-twitter-api-for-android)

http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

Comment: I've already looked at Twitter4j, and it does not provide the functionality I want. I specifically stated I want a browser window to open up, twitter4j does not do this.

Comment: I'm a little confused why you would want a browser window to open up? Especially from your app? If you want your app to actually open up the person's browser then you might want to use JavaScript and HTML to create a local page they would open with the tweet you wanted. Maybe you have an idea, but general best practice for an app would be not to have people leave the app if not necessary.